# How can I catch Error from Node.js user Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

In the user model schema, I give `first_name` to `require` and `email` to `unique` and `require`, when I save the data in the database I would like to send a response if the user will not send the `first_name`. how can we do this without add manually conditions?

I'm adding manually conditions for this operation

```
exports.saveuser = async (req, res) => {
  const { first_name, email } = req.body;

  if (!first_name || !email)
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'All the data require' });

  const user = User.findOne({ email });

  if (user) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Email already exist' });
  }

  const user = new User({
    first_name,
    email,
  });

  await user.save();
};
```

in the above code, I add conditions manually, but I don't want to add all the conditions every time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post `User` schema declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow express Validator. It pretty industry standard. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/
Below is the example:

```
  router.PUT(
    `/api/user`,
    auth,
    validate(UserValidator.saveUser),
    UserController.saveUser,
  );
```